# using getline to parse a string and put it into a linked list c++

Tags: c++, getline, singly-linked-list, stringstream

I have been tasked with writing the classic "shopping cart" linked list project in c++. Each of my nodes has an itemname, an itemcost, and a next. I use a function called insertNode(string name, double cost) that builds the list in alphabetical order. The input is a text file where the first line is the budget and every line after that is in the form of "Itemname, itemcost". I use getline() and stringstream to read the lines of the file and check if it is a string or a number. It works well until I hit a line with an item that is two words (ex: "Ice cream, 4.50"). Visual Studios tells me that it throws a "read access violation" exception, . I haven't had any luck googling my problem because it's so specific (keeping white space in string parse + reading string from file + putting it into a linked list). If y'all could give me any direction (+ any general coding tips) it would be greatly appreciated!! This is the last thing I have left on this assignment. Apologies for poor formatting, I'm kinda new here!

Example input (in a .txt file):

15.00
Apples, 1.50
Broccoli, 2.00
Yogurt, 4.00
Chocolate, 3.80
Paper towels, 2.20
Milk, 1.70
Ice cream, 4.50

main.cpp:

```
//  main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "List.h"

bool isNum(string);
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

string infilename = ("1.txt");
string outfilename = ("output.txt");

ifstream infile;

List list;
double budget = 0;
string iname;
double iprice = 0;

infile.open(infilename.c_str());

if (infile.fail()) {    //check for file failure (did not open)
    exit(1);
}

string temp;
getline(infile, temp);  //grab the budget, catch exceptions
try {
    budget = stod(temp);
    if (budget < 0)
        throw - 3;
}
catch (int e) {
    return -1;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "No budget given. Exiting";
    return -1;
}

string line = "";
string tempdata;
bool proceed = true;
double tempcost = 0;

while (!infile.eof()){
    getline(infile, line);
    istringstream ss;   //create ss object
    ss.str(line);       //converts string to stringstream
    if (isNum(line)) {  //is line a number (price)?
        proceed = false;    //yes, is the end of the line
    }

    if (proceed) {          //no, "import" name & cost using stringstream
        getline(ss, line, ',');
        getline(ss, tempdata);
        bool duplicated = list.isDuplicate(line);   //checks if name is already included in the list

        try {
            if (!duplicated && stod(tempdata) > 0) {        //make sure the item doesn't already exist & the price is a positive number
                tempcost = stod(tempdata);
                list.insertNode(line, tempcost);    //everything looks great, add it to the list
            }
        }
        catch (...) { /* price is not a number, item is already in list*/
        }
    }
    proceed = true;

}
infile.close();

cout << "unaltered, sorted list: " << endl;
list.displayList();
cout << endl;

return 0;
}

bool isNum(string s) {
int n = s.length();
char char_array[50];
strcpy_s(char_array, s.c_str());

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!isdigit(char_array[i])) {
        return false;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

List.h:

```
// List.h
// hw1
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H


#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class List {
private:

typedef struct Node {   //creates node architecture
    double itemcost;
    string itemname;
    Node* next;
}* ptr;

ptr head;
ptr current;
ptr temp;
ptr tail;
int count;


public:             // where functions go
List();
void insertNode(string addName, double addCost);
bool isEmpty();
bool isDuplicate(string name);
void displayList();

};


#endif /* LIST_H */
```

List.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

List::List() {
head = NULL;
current = NULL;
temp = NULL;
tail = NULL;
count = 0;
}

void List::insertNode(string addName, double addCost) {
ptr nodePtr;
ptr previous = NULL;
bool spotFound;

ptr incomingNode = new Node;
incomingNode->itemcost = addCost;
incomingNode->itemname = addName;
incomingNode->next = NULL;

if (head == NULL) {         //does a list exist already? No
    head = incomingNode;    //since there is no list, incomingNode becomes head & tail
    tail = incomingNode;
    count++;
}
else {                      //yes, list exists
    nodePtr = head;
    spotFound = false;

    while (!spotFound && nodePtr != NULL) {                   //start at head
        if (nodePtr->itemname >= incomingNode->itemname) {    //is the cost of the current node more than or equal to the incomingNode?
            spotFound = true;
        }
        else {
            previous = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
    }
    if (nodePtr == head) {          //is the current the head?
        incomingNode->next = head;  //yes, the incomingNode inserts itself in front of the head
        head = incomingNode;        //the incomingNode now labels itself as head
        count++;
    }
    else {                              //current is not the same as the head
        previous->next = incomingNode;  //the incomingNode gets pointed to by the node after the current (nodePtr)
        incomingNode->next = nodePtr;   //the incomingNode now points to the current one (nodePtr)
        if (nodePtr == NULL){       //is the current node NULL?
            tail = incomingNode;    //if yes, then the incomingNode is actually the last in the list (tail)
        }
         count++;
    }

}
}

bool List::isEmpty() {
if (count == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

bool List::isDuplicate(string name) {
temp = head;
while (temp != NULL) {
    if (temp->itemname == name) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
return false;
}


void List::displayList() {
ptr curr = head;
while (curr) {
    cout << curr->itemname << ", " << curr->itemcost << endl;
    curr = curr->next;
}
}
```

Comment: Does `Paper towels, 2.20` cause a problem?

Comment: yes, both Ice cream and Paper towels cause an issue. I just added a couple cout's to the if (proceed) loop so that it'll tell me what getline is reading in as line and tempdata. When it comes across an itemname that has a space, for some reason it reads the entire line as line and tempdata becomes the previous itemcost. So when it reads the ice cream line, line = "Ice cream, 4.50" and tempdata = 1.70. ADDITIONALLY: I just realized it's skipping every other line ??? so it only read in broccoli, chocolate, milk, etc. and skipped apples, yogurt, paper towels, etc. entirely. RIP me

Comment: Works on my machine, although I did have to add `#include <sstream>`, and fix isNum (just use `s[i]` instead of copying it into a char buffer, make the loop look at the whole string, also accept `'.'` as valid).  Doesn't skip every other line.  I think you will need to use a debugger to see where things are going bad when you run it.

Comment: I fixed the skipping and apparently, in main, changing stringstream ss; ss.str(line); into stringstream ss(line); solves all those problems. & Thanks! adding the library & changing isNum helped smooth it out. It seems to be working well locally. Unfortunately it has to be uploaded to the class's linux server and the files you read from/write to are given in the command line. My professor is having us implement an "ArgumentManager.h" that handles that but I keep getting a segmentation fault. I'll have to see if my classmates have figured it out